# Captcha V2 slow response

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I have this problem last week ago my captcha is so slow in showing the pictures(choose car, storefront, etc.) after I click on them it takes like 3-4 seconds before the next picture comes up.

Comment: What is your question here? What did you try to fix/locate the problem. What code do you run?

Comment: Are you experiencing the issue specific to any browser?